# What does "Hit by X+" mean in cleric's Turn Undead spell?

Tags: cleric, 13th-age

The text of the cleric's Turn Undead spell states what the spell does when the attack roll hits versus MD in several different ways: when it simply "Hits," when it "Hits by 4+," when it "Hits by 8+," or when it "Hits by 12+ or Natural 20."

*What exactly does "Hit by X+" mean?* Does it mean that the natural roll on the die was X or higher, or does it mean that the amount by which the rolled total exceeded the target's MD was X or higher? This language does not appear anywhere else in the book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## To exceed the target's MD by X or more.

I asked the game designer, Rob Heinsoo, for clarification:

> When cleric's Turn Undead says "Hit by 8+" does it mean "hit, and the natural roll was 8 or higher" or "hit, and exceeded the target's MD by 8 or more"? It's the only place in the book that uses that phrasing, so I want to be sure.

He confirmed that it's the latter:

> You're right that it's the only place we used the terminology for hitting and exceeding the defense by 4/8/12, the second possibility you listed.

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/robheinsoo/status/946957525328343040).

Answer (score 3):

The best outcome listed is:

> Hit by 12+ or Natural 20:

A natural 20 is always a hit that shows at least 12 on the d20. If the numbers indicated the natural roll, there would be no need to add "or nat 20" after 12+. The intent thus seems to be **total attack roll at least X over MD**.

Comment: "A natural 20 is always a hit that shows at least 12 on the d20." This phrase is confusing.

Comment: @Bloodcinder If you roll a natural 20 on an attack, both "it is a hit" and "the d20 shows a number over 11" are true.

Comment: I'm sorry, the wording of the post makes sense now that you've explained it, but it's a bit confusing at a casual glance. I'm not sure how to improve the phrasing, but I request that the mods leave these comments in place for clarification.